# Systemd auto mount -- slower speed versus GVFS and AutoFS. Why?

Tags: systemd

I just set up systemd to see if its behavior would be preferrable to my previous solution, autofs. What I found in the end was kind of surprising, as the systemd mount performed the slowest when compared to GVFS and AutoFS. I got to wondering if this is a known thing or if one of my settings/flags in the config files might be off. Curious if anybody would be able to provide any insight.

Config files below:

```
jason@JasT470:/etc/systemd/system$ cat mnt-systemd-vault.mount 
[Mount]
What=//10.13.0.200/vault
Where=/mnt/systemd/vault
Type=cifs
Options=rw,noauto,_netdev,x-systemd.automount,cache=none,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials
SloppyOptions=on
DirectoryMode=0755
TimeoutSec=0

jason@JasT470:/etc/systemd/system$ cat mnt-systemd-vault.automount
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
After=remote-fs-pre.target
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/systemd/vault
DirectoryMode=0755
TimeoutIdleSec=1800

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

For reference, the 3 tests were done over AC wireless copying a 2.0 GB ISO file to my laptop. All 3 scenarios were identical.

AutoFS = 60 MB/s
GVFS = 35 MB/s
SystemD = 20 MB/s

Any ideas?

Comment: What does this have to do with systemd? Systemd doesn't implement CIFS. You can tell it to mount as aufs if you want. There's no difference between manually mounting as CIFS and this except that this happens automatically at boot.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. At the end of the day I'm comparing the behaviors of these options and wondering why they're different. Something has to be different to warrant the speed differences I'm seeing. Gvfs is one thing but the other two I don't understand the wide contrast.

Comment: Your question repeatedly stresses that it's systemd that's slow, when systemd can be used to mount in any of these ways (gvfs, aufs, cifs), and what happens after mounting has nothing to do with systemd. Maybe you should edit your question to ask why CIFS is slow.

Comment: I understand. What you're saying makes sense when you put it like that. The snag in my mind is unless there's something in these setups I'm missing, both systemd and autofs should be using cifs. Here's my autofs config for my cifs share at home for comparison to the systemd setup above (sorry, not sure how to format in comment field to make this cleaner, so here's a pastebin instead http://paste.ubuntu.com/26057805/ ) 

Is there anything to suggest systemd and autofs are not using the same approach that I'm simply missing?

Comment: Simple way: mount the cifs manually using the mount command, instead of using systemd

Comment: That doesn't really solve this, as that's not happening automatically on an as-needed basis. Goal is to have applications that "tie" into centralized data. i.e. I can open Rhythmbox and it sees smb/server/music, etc. Likewise, I'm working on a laptop, so flexibility is key.

Autofs does this, but systemd shows more promise as (according to my testing) it handles resuming from suspend when you resume off network much better (autofs locks up Nautilus for a while after), etc.

I'm simply trying to see what is different with the systemd approach as, unfortunately, it acts considerably slower.

Comment: that's not a solution. That's a test for you to see for yourself whether systemd is, in fact, the cause of the slowdown.

Comment: Ah geez, my apologies. I didn't follow your angle there. Thanks for the follow up.

I tested with mounting via terminal. Someone else told me to tinker with version differences of cifs, so I appended that in my testing as well. When I mounted the cifs share via CLI using vers=2.0, the speed was much more comparable to what I was getting with systemd. Using vers=3.0 was significantly quicker, like autofs. Results in the pastebin for sake of formatting. http://paste.ubuntu.com/26059192/ Thanks for your consistent ideas.

Comment: Think I found it. I went through my terminal history and noticed I didn't have cache=none in my mount -t cifs commands you recommended I run manually to compare. I added it, speed tanked to ~20-ish MB/s. Removed it, speed was back to 60 MB/s. Removed it from the systemd file and for good measure rebooted, and my systemd auto mount speed was very comparable to autofs and back up around 60 MB/s. I'm not sure what exactly it's caching so I may want to look into this more to see how that works, but anyway, I have the systemd auto mount with very solid speed working. Thank you very much muru!